# how to get the groupId from group name in AAD graph API

Tags: .net, azure-active-directory

it is possible to get the groupId from the group name using graph api, i am trying to validate if a user is part of a security group in azure active directory, but only know the group name at a time,

i think https://graph.windows.net/mytenantdomain/isMemberOf only supports groupId

Answer (score 12, accepted):

thanks for your question! You can query /groups with a filter expression to get the Group object for your group and then grab the objectId property to use for the isMemberOf function from that. For example:

```
https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/groups?api-version=1.5&$filter=displayName%20eq%20'Example%20Group'
```

You can learn more about the filterable properties for groups here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/Library/Azure/Ad/Graph/api/entity-and-complex-type-reference#GroupEntity

Hope that helps - Jimaco